# Facebook auto post stopped working

Tags: php, facebook, post

Our company has been using Facebook's `facebook.php` and `base_facebook.php` files to auto-post entries to client's Facebook pages. Recently they have all stopped working and the only error we can get is an unexpected error has occured.

We cannot find a solution to this and we were wondering if anyone in the community has ran into this and can guide us in the right direction?

Comment: It's a very vague error you've encountered. I'm not sure how much help anyone can be with the amount of information detailed here. Are there any further errors? Such as output or error messages? Does manual posting of pages work?

Comment: what exactly you try to post?  There has been a new open graph now which used to post stories to users timelime https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview/

Answer (score 1):

That is because the token may have been expired. As the token is valid is just 2 hours after login.

You need to exchange your old token with a new one which has 60 day validity.
The link exchange will be like this..

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=APP_ID& client_secret=APP_SECRET& grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=YOUR_OLD_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The return response will be a 60-day validity token (something like below)

```
CAAAAjls08023jjFK9238024HDSD&expire=1..................
```

Comment: We will try this Shankar, we did not realize the tokens had an expiration on them. We will regenerate the token for a client and try it. I'll let you know how it works out.